# Immutable.js doc on Map #get

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/get), how does the first line work?

```
get<NSV>(key: K, notSetValue: NSV): V | NSV
get(key: K): V | undefined
```

I get the 2nd line means if you pass a key to `get()`, it will return a value or undefined, but why would you use the first case to pass a NSV in?

Comment: Because `map.get('key', 'default')` is shorter and easier to read than `var value = map.get('key'); if (value === undefined) value = 'default'; value`?

Comment: also covered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208118/554389

Answer (score -1):

It allows you to set a default value to return instead if the specified key does not exist in the collection.

The following are equivalent;

```
var a = (...).get('key') || 'default'
var b = (...).get('key', 'default')
```