# How does immutable.js #get work?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I know how Map() can create an empty Map object, but how does the `get` here work?? Does it mean it will get get the value from the `active` key and if there isn't a key there, it will create an empty Map object? Where is the docs for this?

```
const activeSelector = createSelector(
  rootSelector,
  (root) => root.get('active', Map())
);
```

Comment: A quick Google search [brought up the docs.](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) The docs specifically for `get` can be found [here.](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/get)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how it works.  In your example, if *active* is not a key, it will return a new Map.  This is defined in the docs for [get()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/get)

> Returns the value associated with the provided key, or notSetValue if the Collection does not contain this key.